# calling a function in the <fx:Script> tags

Tags: actionscript-3, function, call, mxml

I am a bit stumped.  I thought it was possible to call a function within the fx:Script tag simply by referencing the function ("display_album()" as in the code below).  It would make sense to have that function call outside the curly braces, but when I do, the debugger in FlashBuilder gives me the 1180 error, call to a possibly undefined method.

I can call the function with a button click (which makes sense too), and I get the proper trace in the FlashBuilder debugger.

But I am curious as to how I can call a function in the  tag without adding a button.  Thanks!

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            public function display_album():void
            {
                var album:String = "The White Album";
                trace (album);

            }

            display_album();

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <s:Button x="192" y="259" label="Button" click = "display_album()"/>

</s:Application>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600"
           initialize="init()">
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        private function init():void
        {
          display_album();
        }

        public function display_album():void
        {
            var album:String = "The White Album";
            trace (album);

        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<s:Button x="192" y="259" label="Button" click = "display_album()"/>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks - I had the same thought and tried your approach earlier, but it still does not work :(  I should see the trace run as soon as I hit debug, without clicking the button - but, no luck.  Thanks!

Comment: Pranav and Mark, thanks, this does work - my mistake, I forgot to add the initialize = init() code at the top of the Application!

Answer (score 0):

You can't call an instance function like that, because it runs before the constructor is called. Since the instance itself has not been initialized yet, there is no scope within with this function can be executed. You can only call class functions before the constructor is called.

You can either convert the method into a class method through the `static` keyword (probably not right in this case), or trigger this method on the `creationComplete` event.